# possible test cases for testing a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In one of the interview I was asked to test a method. The details are mentioned below. Though I could answer , still they were expecting some more test cases. Am I missing any scenarios here ?

```
string concatenatefunc(strin1,string2).
 {
   //returns concatenation
 }
```

This method accepts two string parameters and returns the concatenation. No other details are mentioned. I need to test this method and i have written below scenarios/unit test cases:

1.Pass empty parameters and see empty string is returned

2.Pass valid non empty strings and see the string returned is correct or not.

3.Pass the special characters in the both the parameters and test the response.

4.Pass integers and test the response.

5.pass large strings(not sure what we can give as the max length) and test the response.
....

Anything to add here?

Answer (score 3):

You're not testing for null parameters.

Comment: @tinstaafl Since when?  `""` and `string.Empty != null`

Answer (score 2):

Test for multi language support. An area that many developers fail to test which can give a guy like me problems. I have the danish character 'ø' in my name. This has been a problem in my web based interactions with several VERY BIG companies including software companies, preventing me from logins, accounts, payments etc.

Answer (score 0):

Number 5 will really depend on the size of available resources so testing that might be problematic.

You could add tests for either parameter being empty and see if the non-empty parameter is returned

Same for Passing integers, test if either parameter is integer

Then you could start mixing them empty/integer, non-empty/integer, etc. and reverse